# group_by( ) and mutate( ) do not match sizes

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large data table with multiple columns and a custom function. The data table looks something like that, and there are eight different `bird_ID` types:

```
   GPS_ID bird_ID device_ID devicetype           timestamp       date
1:     NA    350E    202927   ornitela 2022-05-02 00:03:59 2022-05-02
2:     NA    350E    202927   ornitela 2022-05-02 00:03:59 2022-05-02
3:     NA    350E    202927   ornitela 2022-05-02 00:03:59 2022-05-02
4:     NA    350E    202927   ornitela 2022-05-02 00:03:59 2022-05-02
5:     NA    350E    202927   ornitela 2022-05-02 00:03:59 2022-05-02
6:     NA    350E    202927   ornitela 2022-05-02 00:03:59 2022-05-02
```

The custom function calculates the difference in time between the `timestamp` of two rows, and assigns a number in a new column named `Position.Burst.ID`. If the `diff` is more than 5 seconds, the number sequence advances, else it keeps the previously assigned number.

```
pbid <- function(data_table) {
  newbout <- which(c(TRUE, diff(as.POSIXct(data_table$timestamp, tz = "UTC")) >= 5) == T)
  boutind <- rep(seq_along(newbout), diff(c(newbout, (nrow(data_table) + 1))))
  data_table$Position.Burst.ID <- boutind
}
```

This function works great with one `bird_ID`.

```
   GPS_ID bird_ID device_ID devicetype           timestamp       date Position.Burst.ID   
1:     NA    350E    202927   ornitela 2022-05-02 00:03:59 2022-05-02                 1
2:     NA    350E    202927   ornitela 2022-05-02 00:03:59 2022-05-02                 1
3:     NA    350E    202927   ornitela 2022-05-02 00:03:59 2022-05-02                 1
4:     NA    350E    202927   ornitela 2022-05-02 00:03:59 2022-05-02                 1
5:     NA    350E    202927   ornitela 2022-05-02 00:03:59 2022-05-02                 1
6:     NA    350E    202927   ornitela 2022-05-02 00:03:59 2022-05-02                 1
```

I wanted to `group_by(bird_ID)`, so it will start counting from the top for each `bird_ID`

```
data_table %>%
  group_by(bird_ID) %>%
  mutate(Position.Burst.ID = pbid(data_table))
```

That surely didn't work, because:

```
`Position.Burst.ID` must be size 419335 or 1, not 4592293.
```

Any ideas on how to approach this?

I have already tried to create a loop and put the function inside, but that was also a dead-end. And I really wanted to avoid using a `for` loop with this amount of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
data_table %>%
  group_by(bird_ID) %>%
  mutate(Position.Burst.ID = cumsum(timestamp - lag(timestamp, default = timestamp[1]) >= 5) + 1)
```